# Merge/synonymize [materialize] and [materializecss] tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [materialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/materialize) and [materializecss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/materializecss) both refer to the same CSS framework.

> A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design.

I'd like to suggest merge or synonymize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the official name of the library is Materialize (no suffixes), and I didn't see any collisions/ambiguity in the list of questions currently with that tag, I pulled the trigger.

The following tags were merged and corresponding synonyms created:

- [materialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/materialize) ← [materializecss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/materializecss)
- [materialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/materialize) ← [materialize-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/materialize-css)
- [materialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/materialize) ← [materialize-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/materialize-js)